# SQL - Pull products of particular category from a remote WordPress woocommerce db

Tags: mysql, sql, woocommerce-offtopic

I connected to the db and successfully pulled products data. Now I want to to display products from specific category. The store is using woocommerce. The landing page is in different location so I can't import wp functions.

Here's what I come up with so far:

```
SELECT ID, `post_date` ,  `post_title` ,  `post_content` ,  `guid` FROM  `wp_posts` as post

INNER JOIN wp_term_relationships rs ON rs.object_id = post.ID 
INNER JOIN wp_terms t ON t.term_id = rs.term_taxonomy_id 


WHERE  `post_type` =  "product"  
AND  `post_status` =  "publish"     
AND rs.term_taxonomy_id  = 117

ORDER BY post_date DESC LIMIT 5
```

Nothing happens. If I remove `AND rs.term_taxonomy_id  = 117` it works as it did before. 5 oldest product appears. Not the products from specific category. What am I missing here?

Answer (score 2):

I check your query and it's working fine without any errors or empty results. But in addition if you remove `INNER JOIN` from `wp_terms` table its also working because you are not getting anything from that table and it is not used in `WHERE` clause also.

```
SELECT ID, `post_date` ,  `post_title` ,  `post_content` ,  `guid` FROM  `wp_posts` as post

INNER JOIN wp_term_relationships rs ON rs.object_id = post.ID 

WHERE  `post_type` =  "post" //post type post for my example
AND  `post_status` =  "publish"
AND rs.term_taxonomy_id  = 1 //term_taxanomy_id is 1 for my example

ORDER BY post_date DESC LIMIT 5
```

Comment: For post its working fine. But for products its not. Product have texonomy product_cat. When I run this I get "MySQL returned an empty result set (i.e. zero rows)." But I have products in that category.

Comment: ok will check it. :)

Comment: @john254 run this query in your mysql and check is their any result.

Answer (score -3):

```
SELECT 
        `ID`, 
        `post_title`,
        `guid`      
FROM 
        posts 
WHERE 
        post_type='product' and 
        post_status='publish' and 
        ID IN(
                SELECT 
                        object_id 
                FROM 
                        term_relationships 
                WHERE 
                        term_taxonomy_id IN(YOUR_CATEGORY_ID_OR_MULTIPLE_IDS_COMMA_SEPARATED ) and
                        term_taxonomy_id IN(
                                            SELECT 
                                                term_taxonomy_id 
                                            FROM 
                                                term_taxonomy 
                                            where 
                                                taxonomy='product_cat' )
                                           )
```

Comment: Please clean up your code and please file an [edit] and explain what your code does and how it works